# Regular expression for Middle name

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I am trying to find regular expression which will accept 
only one character (small or capital)
and only dot

like

```
M
m
m.
A.
```

I have tried

```
^[A-Z]{1}\ ?\.?$
```

Comment: It is almost ready, use `^[A-Za-z]\.?$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: As the question states this is _Middle Name_. I don't think using anchor will be a good idea. And I think OP has used it in wrong sense too. Unless it's **only** middle name he wishes to match.

Comment: @noob: the OP doesn't specify whether the middle name is actually in situ in the middle of the name or a separate field. I suspect Wiktor has taken this based on the OP's original version.

Comment: You do not need to escape spaces in regex, so your regex should be: `^[A-Z]{1} ?\.?$` if you want an optional space between the letter and period.

Comment: no it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
[A-Za-z]\.?
```

It matches any uppercase or lowercase letter then a possible period